# How pass and use a function callback inside Vue.js directive

Tags: vue.js

I created a new directive to use select2.js, and I want call a callback parameter inside a change event of select2.

The directive code:

```
Vue.directive('select', {
twoWay: true,
priority: 1000,

params: ['options', 'change'],

bind: function() {
    var self = this;
    var vm = this.vm;
    var key = this.expression;
    $(this.el)
        .select2({
            data: this.params.options,
            theme: "bootstrap",
            language: "pt-BR",
            containerCssClass: ':all:'
        })
        .on('change', function() {
            self.set($(self.el).val());
            self.params.change($(self.el).val());
        });

    vm.$set(key, $(this.el).val());
},
update: function(value, oldValue) {
    $(this.el).val(value).trigger('change');
},
unbind: function() {
    $(this.el).off().select2('destroy');
}
```

});

And using:

```
<select v-select="controller" change="getActions">
.... options ...
</select>
```

Solution I found (I do not know if it's the best):

```
...

 .on('change', function() {
    self.set($(self.el).val());
    if(typeof vm[self.params.change] == 'function') vm[self.params.change]($(self.el).val());
  });

...
```

Comment: i believe you need to create it as a component if you want to pass a function as a param/prop. Select2 works much better in my opinion as a component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fiddle showing how you can pass a callback using select2 as a component as opposed to a directive.

https://jsfiddle.net/vbranden/up8kb0j8/

Essentially make the "change" prop a functiob

```
props: {
    change: { type: Function }
}
```

then call it in the change event (im using lodash in my fiddle)

```
$(self.$el).select2(config).on('select2:select select2:unselect', function () {
    if (_.isFunction(self.change)) self.change(v)
})
```

I used select2 in a vue project recently and had a lot of issues with it as a directive. as a component it works much better IMHO

Comment: I found the solution to call the function inside a directive, but i will try your answer and make a component. Thanks for the help.